# Numerically solving the Schrödinger equation on the real line using coordinate transformation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem, finite-difference-methods

Consider the (dimensionally reduced) Schrödinger equation on the real line
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}-&\phi''(x)+V(x)\phi(x)=E\phi(x), \ x \in \mathbb{R} \\ &\lim_{x \to \pm \infty} \phi(x) = 0 \end{aligned} \right. $$
where $V$ is some confining potential.

I would like to solve the above equation problem numerically. If the domain were finite, this could easily be done using e.g. a finite difference method. I had an idea that maybe one could perform a coordinate transformation to bring the problem to a problem defined on a finite domain. Hence let $\xi = \tanh(x)$ and define $\varphi(\xi)=\phi(\mathrm{arctanh}(\xi)) \Leftrightarrow \phi(x) = \varphi(\tanh(x))$ and $\nu(\xi)=V(\mathrm{arctanh}(\xi))$, respectively. The boundary conditions are then implemented as $\phi(\pm1) = 0$. By the chain rule, we have
$$\frac{d\phi}{dx} = (1-\tanh^2(x))\varphi'(\tanh(x)), \ \mathrm{i.e.} \ \frac{d\phi}{dx} = (1-\xi^2)\varphi'(\xi)  $$
and
$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2} = (1-\tanh^2(x))\left[-2\tanh(x)\varphi'(\tanh(x))+(1-\tanh^2(x))\varphi''(\tanh(x))\right],$$
i.e.
$$\frac{d^2\phi}{dx^2} = (1-\xi^2)\left[-2\xi\varphi'(\xi)+(1-\xi^2)\varphi''(\xi)\right].$$

Thus, we get the transformed problem
$$\left\{\begin{aligned}-&(1-\xi^2)\left[-2\xi\varphi'(\xi)+(1-\xi^2)\varphi''(\xi)\right]+\nu(\xi)\varphi(\xi)=E\varphi(\xi), \ \xi \in (-1,1) \\ &\varphi(\pm 1) = 0 \end{aligned} \right. $$

My idea was to solve the reformulated problem as an eigenvalue problem using the finite difference method. Hence let $N$ denote the number of internal points, put $h = 2/(N+1)$, define $\xi_n = nh-1$, $\varphi_n = \varphi(\xi_n)$ and $\nu_n = \nu(\xi_n)$. We have $\xi_0=1$ and $\xi_{N+1}=0$. Use the second order accurate approximations
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
&\varphi'(\xi_n) = (\varphi_{n+1}-\varphi_{n-1})/(2h) +\mathcal{O}(h^2)\\
&\varphi''(\xi) = (\varphi_{n+1}-2\varphi_n+\varphi_{n-1})/h^2 +\mathcal{O}(h^2)
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

Define the vector $\boldsymbol{\xi} = [\xi_1 \dots \xi_N]^N$ and an $N \times N$ matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ by

- $A_{1,1} = 2(1-\xi_1^2)^2/h^2 +\eta_1$
- $A_{1,2} = (1-\xi_1^2)\xi_1/h - (1-\xi_1^2)^2/h^2$
- $A_{n,n-1} = -(1-\xi_n^2)\xi_n/h - (1-\xi_n^2)^2/h^2$, where $1 \leq n \leq N$
- $A_{n,n} = 2(1-\xi_n^2)^2/h^2 +\eta_n$, where $1 \leq n \leq N$
- $A_{n,n+1} = (1-\xi_n^2)\xi_n/h - (1-\xi_n^2)^2/h^2$, where $1 \leq n \leq N$
- $A_{N,N-1} = -(1-\xi_N^2)\xi_N/h - (1-\xi_N^2)^2/h^2$
- $A_{N,N} = 2(1-\xi_N^2)^2/h^2 +\eta_N$

with other elements of $\boldsymbol{A}$ being zero. Then the discretization of the transformed problem is simply the eigenvalue problem
$$\boldsymbol{A}\boldsymbol{\xi} = E\boldsymbol{\xi}.$$
In principle, this can be solved. However, when I do so in practice, I get some unphysical imaginary eigenvalues. This is perhaps not very surprising, since the matrix $\boldsymbol{A}$ is not symmetric, unless I've made a mistake somewhere.

**Question:** Is my approach fundamentally flawed, or is there some way to salvage it?

**EDIT**

After fixing some errors in the code, I no longer seem to get imaginary eigenvalues. However, for a model potential for which I know what the eigenvalues should be, I do not get the right eigenvalues numerically. In particular, most of them are positive, though they should be negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With such a discretization you will get two extremes in quality for the eigenvectors.

- One group of eigenvectors that corresponds to the actual smooth eigen-solutions will minimize the energy-eigenvalue, while being near-orthogonal according to the eigenspaces.
- A second group that maximizes the energy-eigenvalue and will have highly oscillating eigenvectors, the one for the largest eigenvalue having alternating signs in its components, others oscillating with slightly smaller frequencies.
- In the middle there will be a mix of properties of both groups, usually not very useful as numerical approximations.

So for useful results you can only take the lowest third or so of the eigenvalues. One could probably also make a sampling-theorem like argument. For oscillating solutions one needs about 6-10 samples per full oscillation to get a suitable approximation by the piecewise linear approximation. The lowest eigen-solution has a half-oscillation, the next a full oscillation, and so on in half-steps. So with at most $n/6$ oscillations one covers at most $n/3$ eigen-functions.

---

Another approach is to leave the domain as $\Bbb R$ and discretize a middle interval $[-K,K]$. On the outer intervals use WKB approximations $y(x)=C\phi_\pm(x)$ as far-field solutions. Use
$$y(K)=C\phi_+(K),~~y'(K)=C\phi_+'(K)\implies \phi_+'(K)y(K)-\phi_+(K)y'(K)=0$$
and similarly at $-K$ as boundary condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer (I am not able to upvote it because of having too low rep)! Just to clarify: Are the eigenvalues with nonzero imaginary part associated with the enery-maximizing modes? I also seem to get some real but positive eigenvalues which are also unphysical, since they do not correspond to bound states.

Comment: I would say that you have an error if you get large imaginary parts, as your equation is still self-adjoint, so the discretization should be near-self-adjoint. My argument should then apply to the order of the absolute values, and possibly to the order of the real parts alone.

Comment: Alright, thanks! I'll go through my implementation again to see if I can spot any errors. By the way, do you know if my approach is in any way standard? When I've looked around on the internet, it seems to be much more common to it the way you suggest, i.e. solve the equation on a finite sub-interval and use approximate far-field solutions.

Comment: Hi again! I did find some mistakes in my code. After correcting them, there no longer appear to be problems with negative eigenvalues. However, chossing a potential for which I know the exact eigenvalues, I still do not seem to get the correct eigenvalues numerically. In particular, most of the eigenvalues which I find numerially are positive, though they should be negative.

Comment: Hi again! I see now that I can get fairly accurate values for the energies for a model potential where I know what the energies should be. The problem is of course that for a general potential, I don't know how many of the values I find are actually sensible. The rule-of-thumb of taking the lowest third of the eigenvalues could be useful, however.

Comment: You can always solve the same problem with half the step size and compare how close the energy values are.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Yes, that comparison seems to indicate fairly well which eigenvalues are reliable.